# Give the general solution of the $2\times 2$ inhomogeneous system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

> Give the general solution of the system: $$X'(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} X(t)+\begin{pmatrix} 2e^{2t} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

I manage to come to the general solution to the homogenous but when I get finding a particular solution I'm messing up.

Comment: Have you tried a particular solution of the form $e^{2t}$ times a constant vector?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm new to this whole Stack Exhange thing!

Comment: It can't be since $e^{2t}$is in the homogenous solution.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of the matrix are $2$ and $4$, one of which is in $e^{2t}$.  So try $$X(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}ate^{2t}\\bte^{2t}\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: shouldn't it be $\begin{pmatrix} (at+b)e^{2t} \\ (ct+d)e^{2t} \end{pmatrix} $?

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking you already have $b$ and $d$ from the homogeneous solution.  I might be wrong; I was thinking of the scalar diff eqn.

Comment: I'm not sure, because if it was indeed $\begin{pmatrix} ate^{2t} \\ bte^{2t} \end{pmatrix} $ a and b would be 0 since they never equal $ 2e^{2t}$ .

Comment: Remember the derivative on the left-hand side.

Comment: Ohh maybe that was it, I was able to get values for a and c and b in function of d.

Comment: I'll try it and get back